# Fancybox plugin adds display none to the anchor

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

Im using this plugin [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).
Everything works just fine but when i click on the anchor fancybox adds display none to it... So when I close fancybox popup i canot see the items that were clicked.
my code looks like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" href="{link" data-fancybox-group="gal1" title="title">
                <img src="img" alt="imgTitle"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and js

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Comment: your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/McKGD/ .... must be something else. Got a link?

Comment: im using overflow hidden for the  `ul` can that be the problem ?

Comment: don't think so http://jsfiddle.net/McKGD/2/